# "Open In Terminal" or "Show On Disk" not working

Tags: android-studio, terminal, google-chrome-os, androidappsonchromeos, crostini

On AVD manager, when I click on "show on disk", it doesn't show on disk. Instead it opens a new chrome window like so.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mqirY.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jtqBX.png)

Similarly "Open In Terminal" in Nemo, doesn't work either.

Maybe I've configured the linux terminal wrong on my chromebook?

Comment: Can you please be more specific about your issue. And general tip try restarting the whole android studio, restarting your laptop and look for any software/android studio update

Comment: I've updated the description. Thanks.